# count of variable values across columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, count

I want to do a count of the number of times a number appears in a df. I specifically want a variable that outputs the # and the frequency count. Here is some data, although this is an abridged version of the data. I have close to 45 columns.

```
a1  b1   c1
23  23   1
24  4    18
2   2    2
18  NA   NA
```

I want this:

```
value  freq
1       1
2       2
4       1
18      2
23      2
24      1
```

I tried this, but it's not doing what I want it to.

```
library(plyr)  
count(df, vars = NULL, wt_var = NULL)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the data.frame, get the `table`, convert to a `data.frame`, and `order` the rows based on the 'Freq' column

```
out <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(df1)))
out[order(-out$Freq),]
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, reshape to 'long' format `pivot_longer` and get the `count` of the 'value' column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    count(value) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  value     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     2     3
#2    18     2
#3    23     2
#4     1     1
#5     4     1
#6    24     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a1 = c(23L, 24L, 2L, 18L), b1 = c(23L, 4L, 2L, 
NA), c1 = c(1L, 18L, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun! I used the first method you outlined and that worked. Is there a way to have the frequency listed in descending order?